# Is it ever convenient to mod out reparameterizations in a category of spaces?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Often we choose nice categories of spaces by choosing full subcategories of larger categories of spaces. Is it ever convenient to instead look at subcategories of these supercategories by modding out by the reparameterization relation? To make my question concrete: are there theorems or constructions that work in the wide subcategory of $\mathbf{Top}$, obtained by modding hom sets by the reparameterization relation, that do not work in $\mathbf{Top}$ itself? Feel free to replace $\mathbf{Top}$ with any other category of spaces that might keep the question relevant. Thanks!

**Edit.** I should probably add that the notion of reparameterization I am using is: given two maps $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$, $f$ may be reparameterized to $g$ precisely when there is some automorphism $\phi: X\circlearrowleft$ such that $f\phi=g$.

Comment: Is this a congruence? That is to say, is composition of equivalence classes well defined?

Comment: Well, composition in the ambient category must commute with the quotient functor, because if $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ and $f',g':Y\rightarrow Z$, with $f\sim g$ and $f'\sim g'$, there must be automorphisms $\phi,\psi$ such that $f\phi=g$ and $f'\psi=g'$. Then we get a commutative rectangle that displays that $\phi$ also reparameterizes $f'f$ to $g'g$. Then we can choose either composite and take the equivalence class to give a well-defined composite in the quotient category.

Comment: If $f \circ \phi = g$ and $f' \circ \psi = g'$ then $g' \circ g = f' \circ \psi \circ f \circ \phi$, but what you want is $g' \circ g = f' \circ f \circ \theta$ for some $\theta$.